# C++Builder subform doesn't show on taskbar and minimize is placed on the desktop not the taskbar?

Tags: winapi, modal-dialog, c++builder, vcl, tform

Using C++Builder and opening a vcl subform with `ShowModal()` results with no taskbar entry and minimize doesn't minimize to taskbar (it's placed in lower left of the desktop).

Is there a setting I should enable for that to occur?

TIA!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only a top-level *unowned* window that has the `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` style applied to it will automatically appear on the Taskbar.

By default, sub-forms are owned by either the active `TForm`, the `TApplication::MainForm`, or the `TApplication` window, depending on various criteria at the time the sub-form is displayed.  Thus, why they do not appear on the Taskbar.

If you want a sub-form to appear on the Taskbar, you can either:

- override its virtual [`CreateParams()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.CreateParams) method to set the `TCreateParams::WndParent` field to `0` (or to the desktop `HWND` returned by [`GetDesktopWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdesktopwindow)), and to add the `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` style to the `TCreateParams::ExStyle` field.
- alternatively, use [`ITaskbarList::AddTab()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-itaskbarlist-addtab) to manually add a button to the Taskbar and associate it with the `HWND` returned by the sub-form's `Handle` property.